# how to make default value in wp -property

Tags: wordpress

HI i am working on real estate website in wordpress and i am using [wp-propery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-property/) plugin for this.

this is an option to create attribute . i have create one attribute with `province name` and its appearing correctly but i don't want that there initial value appear `any`, i just want that there should directly first value appear .

you can check my site link [here on](http://ruthwiens.com/)  . In right side first thing is province

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to do the same thing on one of our sites and the only way I found to do this is by changing some code. You need to open the file: template-functions.php, located at wp-content/plugins/wp-property/templates/template-functions.php. Then you need to find the line: "case 'dropdown':" (without the double quotes), it should be around line 1400. A few lines below that there should be a line:

```
<option value="-1"><?php _e( 'Any' ,'wpp' ) ?></option>
```

Change that line to:

```
<?php if (strcmp($attrib, "province") == 0){ ?>
    <option value="Manitoba">Manitoba</option>
    <option value="-1"><?php _e( 'Any' ,'wpp' ) ?></option>
<?php }
else{  ?>
    <option value="-1"><?php _e( 'Any' ,'wpp' ) ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

This will make Manitoba the default value for the Province drop down.

A couple of things, Manitoba will be the default everywhere on the site that you have a Province drop down and, if you ever update your WP-Properties plugin, this change will be lost so you need to remember where you make this change so you can modify it again in the future if you need to.

Comment: really thanks for your support , i already figured out this, but i personally appreciate this

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. Did you figure out a different way or is your solution similar to mine?

Comment: similar to you . i have also changed that function for removing any in dropdown :)